# Selectively encoding SOAP Sections using MTOM and WSE 3

Tags: c#, .net, mtom, wse

We are using WSE 3.0 to setup security header options for invoking a webservice. The webservice also expects an attachment in MTOM format.

When we try to enable ClientMode = "On" in the App.config file of the windows application, it removes the Base64 encoded public key in the "wsse:BinarySecurityToken" with `<xop:Include href="cid:1.635864617295207824@example.org" />` (in our SOAP request). Because of this, webservice returns an "Invalid Security Header" error.

Is there a way we could selectively MTOM encode specific section like "soap:Body", where we have our MTOM attachment. Or what would be a possible solution for this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding the KeyInfo field manually to the Soap Request.